# QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: qt, qt4

I have compiled `qmysql` driver plugin and placed debug and release `.dll` and `.lib` files in `\plugins\sqldrivers`. But when i try `qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();` it still get `("QSQLITE", "QODBC3", "QODBC", "QPSQL7", "QPSQL")`and `QMYSQL` driver is not available.Any idea?

Qt version : 4.8.4
 Compiler : MSVC2010

OS : windows vista (64bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application needs libmysql.dll which you can find in the MySQL installation directory. You can copy it to the Qt bin directory or in the same directory of your .exe

Note that you need to restart your IDE (Qt Creator or what ever IDE) after you place new dll files in \plugins\sqldrivers or Qt bin directory.

Comment: I think the better way is to include path to libmysql.dll folder in user PATH variable.