# Qt/MySQL requests work on my computer but not on others

Tags: mysql, qt, dll

I have developed an application on Windows under Qt Creator that recognize music played by the computer.

I have added a table of music played by all users of this app.

The table is linked to a database hosted on internet.

I use this request to get all music and fill the table :

```
void DataTable::refreshData(){
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("mysql1.alwaysdata.com");
    db.setDatabaseName("mymusicrecognition_mmr");
    db.setUserName("user");
    db.setPassword("pass");
    db.open();
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM mmr ORDER BY id DESC");
    int i = 0;
    while (query.next() && i<500) {
        QString music = query.value(1).toString();
        QString album = query.value(2).toString();
        QString time = query.value(3).toString();
        QString date = query.value(4).toString();
        item(i,0)->setText(music);
        item(i,1)->setText(album);
        item(i,2)->setText(time);
        item(i,3)->setText(date);
        i++;
    }
    db.close();

}
```

and this request to add the last music identified by the user's computer :

```
void DataTable::addRowInData(QString artist, QString title,QString album){
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("mysql1.alwaysdata.com");
    db.setDatabaseName("mymusicrecognition_mmr");
    db.setUserName("user");
    db.setPassword("pass");
    db.open();
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec(QString("INSERT INTO mmr VALUES (NULL,'%1','%2','%3','%4')")
    .arg(artist+" - "+title).arg(album).arg(QTime::currentTime().toString("H:mm:ss")).arg(QDate::currentDate().toString("d.MM.yyyy")));
    db.close();

}
```

The problem is that when I install the app on my computer, all requests work, but when I install it on another computer (and another IP), the table is empty and no music is added.

Note : I added those dll in the program folder :

Qt5Sql.dll

qsqlmysqld.dll

qsqlmysql.dll

libmysql.dll

Thank u in advance

Comment: try to compile the application with CONFIG += CONSOLE and start it from a console to see the output. Also take into account that the dlls from QT ending in *d.dll are debug dlls so deploy with the needed dlls depending on the type of build you make (debug or release).

Comment: thank u I'll try that.
Also, i will delete qsqlmysqld.dll

Comment: Ok, I tried to put qsqlmysql.dll in a folder "sqldrivers" and added CONFIG += CONSOLE in .pro file, I have this message in console :


QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Comment: After this line does it give you a list of available drivers? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077582/qmysql-driver-not-loaded) will be useful. Also you can try to put `plugins/sqldrivers/qsmysql.dll`.

Comment: plugins/ folder does not work and the list of drivers is empty, it says :

"QSqlDatabas: available drivers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved :
appraently, I used qsqlmysql.dll from 5.3.1 version of Qt and Qt5Sql.dll from 5.2.1 (because I add a problem of execution from 5.3.1) so I took the 2 dlls from 5.2.1 and it works !!

Answer (score 0):

The sql-driver dll does not belong in the application folder. The sqldrivers belong in there own subdirectory. As already stated in comments, debug (*d.dll) libraries are not required in release.

```
ApplicationFolder\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll
ApplicationFolder\Qt5Sql.dll
ApplicationFolder\libmysql.dll
```